# Find MIN -values but maintain row values in PHP mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, min

I have a table with 32 rows, with pairwise rows containing same "name-values", but with different raspberry-values (respectively "one" and "two".)
[image]

I want to extract each row with a unique name and the lowest average_distance - giving me 16 rows, and for that I am using this query:

```
SelectFinally();

function SelectFinally (){
    $con = connectToDB();
     $sql = "SELECT name,MIN(average_distance),raspberry From average GROUP BY name";
    $result= mysqli_query($con,$sql);
   $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

   echo "number of rows"  .$num_rows ."<br />";
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  {
        extract($row);
        $name = $row['name'];       
       $distance = $row['MIN(average_distance)'];    //."<br />";
       $raspberry = $row['raspberry'];       //."<br />";

echo "select inside selectFinally     name: " .$name  ."    distance:  " .$distance  ."  raspberry    "   .$raspberry ."<br />"; 


    }
```

}

This query gives me the lowest values of the average_distance allright, BUT it messes up my raspberry values. e.g. blå_bil should have a raspberry value of "two", hence it has the lowest average_distance - value.
I can not seem to get it right. Would somebody please help me to get it right?

[image: browser output]

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
SELECT a.name, a.raspberry
FROM   average a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT   name, MIN(average_distance) as avg_dist
    FROM     average
    GROUP BY name
) a2 ON a.name = a2.name AND a.average_distance = a2.avg_dist
```

Instead of `SELECT name,MIN(average_distance),raspberry From average GROUP BY name`

Comment: If any pair of rows with the same name also have the same average_distance, this query will return both rows. This might, or might not, be the desired behaviour.

Comment: It really does. I tested it on the following table: `CREATE TABLE average(name VARCHAR(32), average_distance INT, raspberry VARCHAR(4));
INSERT INTO average VALUES('a', 7, 'one'), ('a', 7, 'two'), ('b', 2, 'one'), ('b', 4, 'two');` and two rows were returned with name "a".

Comment: ok I understand what you mean now...I guess OP wouldn't sweat too much to modify the query and add his own logic in that case

Comment: Hi Matha
When I extract the data from the method, I get the name and raspberry - but not the average_distance -  is this line correct then?
 $distance = $row['MIN(average_distance)'];

Comment: no, it should be `$distance = $row['avg_dist'];` see my Inner Join query..I'm aliasing the `MIN(average_distance) as avg_dist` if you want to keep it ` $distance = $row['MIN(average_distance)'];` then you inner query shouldn't use aliasing it should be just `MIN(average_distance)`

Answer (score 0):

thanks Nishant Matha
It worked - I simply needed to add te raspberry in my first select. Now it adds the average_distance to the output.

```
    $sql = "SELECT a.name, a.average_distance, a.raspberry 
from average a 
INNER JOIN
(
select name,MIN(average_distance) AS avg_dist,raspberry
FROM average
GROUP BY name
)
a2 ON a.name=a2.name AND a.average_distance = a2.avg_dist ";
```